# Bitcoin.conf doesn't exist in my Windows 10

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am in dire need to prune the blockchain because of the storage space on my computer being completely clogged up now. But I cannot locate the files. I have found the directory, but the bitcoin.conf file simply doesn't exist. Please help me!

Comment: create it.................

Answer (score 3):

In Bitcoin Core, go to Settings > Options and click the button labeled "Open Configuration File". This will make a bitcoin.conf file and open it in a text editor. Add the lines that you want (probably `prune=550`) and save the file. Then restart Bitcoin Core.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create it under `%APPDATA%/bitcoin`
and define the needed parameters as presented in https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin

there is a prun parameters to set in order to allow the prune mode.